# How to break a every loop in tcl

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Need to run a piece of code for certain duration when a master job is running.
Basically some tool is writing a logFile, during logfile is written i used grep for Errors/Warnings from that logFile.

I use every loop which checks for the condition of job being running and then write a Error/Warning database, if job is not running it will print message.
Problem: once it founds job is running, every loop is kicked on it never stops even the else condition is false.

I used break in if loop, but didn't work.
How to stop every loop, please suggest.

```
proc every {ms body} {
     eval $body
     after $ms [info level 0]
}

proc run_this_loop {} {
    catch {set job_name [exec qstat | awk {{print $3}} | grep liberate]} error
    if {[string match *abnormally* $error]} {
        puts "No background liberate job is found\n"
    } else {
        every 10000 {grepLoop}
    }
}

every 1000 {run_this_loop}
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple way is to save the id of the `after` invocation and use it to cancel:

```
proc every {ms body} {
    global id
    eval $body
    set id [after $ms [info level 0]]
}

every 2000 {puts foo}

after cancel $id
```

Documentation:
[after](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/after.htm),
[eval](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/eval.htm),
[global](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/global.htm),
[info](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I realized my bullish code.

```
 proc run_this_loop {} {
   catch {set job_name [exec qstat | awk {{print $3}} | grep liberate]} error
      if {[string match *abnormally* $error]} {
      puts "No background liberate job is found\n"
      } else {
     grepLoop
      }
    }
```

I don't need every inside else loop, removing every solves my problem.
Please suggest in case any optimized way of doing it...
I still needs to know how to break a every loop.